# More Concise Code for Dynamically Referencing ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, combobox

I'm a newbie to VBA.  This is also my first post here.  I'm creating an Excel spreadsheet that is going to be used as a form.  There are about 50 comboboxes that are required.

Each section of the code works however, I'd like to know if there is a more concise way to do the following:

- Populate the combobox from a range on a different worksheet (section 1 below)
- Validate the option selected.  If the selection is invalid then throw an error msg only once.  It's currently thrown twice.  (section 2 below)
- once tab or enter is pressed, move to an active cell. (section 3 below)

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  With Worksheets("Sheet6")

          ComboBox1.List = .Range("AC10:AC" & .Range("AC" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
          ComboBox2.List = .Range("AC10:AC" & .Range("AC" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
          ComboBox3.List = .Range("AC10:AC" & .Range("AC" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
          ComboBox4.List = .Range("AC10:AC" & .Range("AC" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
          ComboBox5.List = .Range("AC10:AC" & .Range("AC" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
          ComboBox6.List = .Range("AC10:AC" & .Range("AC" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
          ComboBox7.List = .Range("AC10:AC" & .Range("AC" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
          ComboBox8.List = .Range("AC10:AC" & .Range("AC" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
          ComboBox9.List = .Range("AC10:AC" & .Range("AC" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

      End With

  End Sub

  Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

      If ComboBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then

           MsgBox "Entity Does Not Exist"
           Range(ComboBox1.LinkedCell).Select
           Application.EnableEvents = False
           ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
           Application.EnableEvents = True
      End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
      Select Case KeyCode
          Case 9
              ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
          Case 13
              ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
          Case Else

      End Select
  End Sub
  ```

  Update* - I've figured out section 2.  New code is simply:

  ```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
      If ComboBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then
           ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1
           MsgBox "Entity Does Not Exist"
      End If
  End Sub
  ```

Update** - This is a bit better for section 2:

```
    Private Sub WorkSheet_Activate()
    With Worksheets("Sheet6")
    Dim cb As ComboBox
    Dim i As Long

        For i = 1 To 9
        Set cb = Sheet3.Shapes("ComboBox" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object
            cb.List = .Range("AC10:AC" & .Range("AC" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        Next i
        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you're handling all of your ComboBoxes in much the same way and so create a single VBA class that you can attach to each ComboBox for initialization, validation, and use. Take a look at an explanation I created for CheckBoxes in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594657/a-checkbox-that-refers-to-itself-in-excel-vba/31598308#31598308), and see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You improved the main parts, but there is one more optimization I'd include:

extract the last used row only once, outside the For loop:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim rngList As Range, i As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet6")
        Set rngList = .Range("AC10:AC" & .Range("AC" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
    For i = 1 To 9
        Sheet3.Shapes("ComboBox" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object.List = rngList
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then
         ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1
         MsgBox "Entity Does Not Exist"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    IIf KeyCode = 9, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```