# Write to the cell next to a checkbox when that checkbox is checked

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have a to do list in excel. When a check box is checked a macro is ran that selects a specific cell and adds values to offsets of that cell. The problem is I have 600 check boxes and they all need their own code to reference the correct cells.

```
private sub checkbox1_click ()
Range ("I2").offset(0,3).value= "hello world"
Sub end
```

I want something like this:

```
Range ("location of checkbox I just checked").offset(0,3).value= "hello world"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be easier if you are using ActiveX control checkboxes instead of Form control.

With ActiveX control checkboxes, you can refer to the object as a part of `Me`, which points to the worksheet itself and use something like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then

        Me.CheckBox1.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "hello world"

    End If

End Sub
```

If you can't use ActiveX controls, please let me know and I can adjust my answer. Note that you could also look at more information on how to make a checkbox refer to itself by looking at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594657/a-checkbox-that-refers-to-itself-in-excel-vba).

In the answer from PeterT, you can also see how to use a Class Module to avoid the problem of having one macro per checkbox. Here, I'm copying the relevant part of the answer:

> [...] Create a class module that you can instantiate for any number of
>   CheckBoxes.
>
> **Code for Class module MyCheckBoxClass**
>
> ```
> Dim WithEvents cbControl As MSForms.CheckBox
>
> Private controlName As String
>
> Public Sub cbControl_Click()
>     Debug.Print controlName & " is now " & cbControl.Value
>     If cbControl.Value = True Then
>         Range("CheckBoxCount") = Range("CheckBoxCount") + 1  'choose to store on the sheet
>         groupCheckBoxCount = groupCheckBoxCount + 1          'or in a variable
>     Else
>         Range("CheckBoxCount") = Range("CheckBoxCount") - 1
>         groupCheckBoxCount = groupCheckBoxCount - 1
>     End If
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub Attach(newCB As MSForms.CheckBox, newName As String)
>     Set cbControl = newCB
>     controlName = newName
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub Class_Initialize()
>     controlName = ""
> End Sub
> ```
>
> **Code in a regular code module:**
>
> ```
> Public groupClickCount As Integer
> Private cbCollection As Collection
>
> Public Sub SetUpControlsOnce()
>     Dim thisCB As MyCheckBoxClass
>     Dim ctl As OLEObject
>     Dim cbControl As MSForms.CheckBox
>
>     If cbCollection Is Nothing Then
>         Set cbCollection = New Collection
>     End If
>
>     For Each ctl In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects
>         If TypeName(ctl.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
>             '--- this is an ActiveX CheckBox
>             Set thisCB = New MyCheckBoxClass
>             thisCB.Attach ctl.Object, ctl.name
>             cbCollection.Add thisCB
>         End If
>     Next ctl
> End Sub
> ```

Of course, you would have to replace "Sheet1" with the appropriate name for your sheet and

```
If cbControl.Value = True Then
    Range("CheckBoxCount") = Range("CheckBoxCount") + 1  'choose to store on the sheet
    groupCheckBoxCount = groupCheckBoxCount + 1          'or in a variable
Else
    Range("CheckBoxCount") = Range("CheckBoxCount") - 1
    groupCheckBoxCount = groupCheckBoxCount - 1
End If
```

**With**

```
If cbControl.Value = True Then

    cbControl.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "hello world"

End If
```

And finally, I would suggest to run the `SetUpControlsOnce` macro when you open the workbook by including it in the Open Event of the Workbook Object (Thisworkbook). ie.:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call SetUpControlsOnce
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect!!!!! This will cut down my file size by half!!!!! Thank you so much